# useLazyAsyncData not working because of data structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3 and Contentful as my CMS, I am trying to implement useLazyAsyncData but I get an error of Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Can't read properties of null (reading '0')
I think it is because of my data structure that has [0], like data[0].items[0].fields.title
Below is the console log of my data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY9CF.png)

Is there any way to remove the [0] in the structure of my data so I can access them directly like the title by doing data.title?

useAsyncData is working but I want to use a skeleton loading.

```
const {
  data: entry,
  pending,
  error,
} = await useLazyAsyncData('entry', () => {
  return Promise.all([
    $contentful.getEntries({
      content_type: 'blog',
      limit: 1,
      'fields.slug': slug,
    }),
  ])
    .then((entry) => entry)
    .catch(console.error);
});

blogs = toRaw(entry.value);
console.log(blogs);
```

I have tried the useAsyncData and it is working but I want to use skeleton loading thats why I want the pending status.

I have also tried using different API provider and it works as expected. Their database do not have [0] on it.

Comment: It's a mistake to use toRaw(entry.value) . The result is not available at this point, that's the purpose of using lazy. Stick to the reactive workflow and composition api. It's not obvious that 0 element is guaranteed to exist. In case this is really so just transform the response the way you need. If you need 0 element then destructure it, `.then(([entry]) => entry)`. This is basic JS problem at this point. No `blogs` is necessary

Comment: I want to use lazy so I can get the status and use skeleton loading.